# Mapping allHeaderFields in AlamofireObjectMapper response

Tags: ios, swift, mapping, alamofire

I am using [`AlamofireObjectMapper`](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper)

and response from my server is in JSON but it also include some key in the headers

```
Alamofire.request(URL).responseObject { (response: DataResponse<MyMappable>) in

let weatherResponse = response.result.value
print(weatherResponse?.location)

}
```

and my map able class is like this

```
class MyMappable: Mappable {
var location: String?

required init?(map: Map){

}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    location <- map["location"]

   }
}
```

all of the above code is working but my problem is I want to map some value is header, I can get these header in the response only

```
let allHeaders = response.response?.allHeaderFields
if let headers = allHeaders as? [String: String], let someValue = headers["key"] 

{
  print("my value is: \(someValue)")
                }
```

but I want to map it in the **MyMappable** class, is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a way to map header Fields with payload
what I could find was, we can get all header fields from response and store it in our class in two ways.
first one is like this

```
    Alamofire.request(URL).responseObject { (response: DataResponse<MyMappable>) in    
let myMappable = response.result.value
```

> ```
> myMappable.allHeaderFields  = response.response?.allHeaderFields
> ```

```
print(myMappable?.location)

}
```

and the second way (which one used by me) if you are using generic class as parent then you can cast your response like blow

```
 Alamofire.request(URL).responseObject { (response: DataResponse<MyMappable>) in

let myMappable = response.result.value
if let genericResp = myMappable as? GenericResponse<AnyGeneric> {
     genericResp.mHeaders = response.response?.allHeaderFields
   }

}
```